# server.servlet.context-path is not working over AWS enviroment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have just host my springboot application (WAR) over AWS elastic beanstack, but found one strange issue

server.servlet.context-path= /app-name/api/v0

This is working on localhost perfectly fine but after deploying over aws its not working, however all APIs are working without context path from AWS as well:

Example :

```
http://awsaddress.com/login  -> its working, but it should like 

 http://awsaddress.com/app-name/api/v0/login  -> its not working
```

[image]

Comment: Check whether you are using a different spring profile on aws and if so ensure that the servlet context path is not getting overriden for that profile. Try  providing the servlet contxt as a command line parameter at the time of deployment to ensure that it is not environment dependend.

Comment: I didn't use any profile thing for now,  only db details and context path in application.properties file in apringboot, please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Since you are using elastic bean stack make sure that the environment variables added does not have a servlet context path specified in it. Also are you deploying in an external tomcat or just using war or some other reason like since you are using jsp ?

Comment: server.servlet.context-path= ${BRAINY_CONTEXT_PATH:/brainy/api/v0}  this is entry in property file, please see in screenshot , I have set same in aws environment as well, I am not using external tomcat like, just uploaded WAR file in AWS elastic beanstack

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but i was facing the same problem.
In my case the solution was to add following lines in application.properties:

```
server.contextPath = /artifactId
server.servlet.contextPath = /artifactId
```